# How do I handle the creation/destruction of many objects in memory effectively?

Tags: windows, memory-management

Im in the process of making a game of my own. One of the goals is to have as many objects within the world as possible. In this game, many objects will need to be created in some unpredictable period of time (like a weapon firing will create an object) and once that projectile hits something, the object will need to be destroyed aswell (and maybe the thing it hits).

So i was wondering what the best way to handle this in memory is. Ive thought about creating a stack or table, and adding the pointers to those objects there, and creating and destroying those objects on demand, however, what if several hundred (or thousand) objects try to be created or destroyed at once between frames? I want to keep a steady and fluid frame rate, and such a surge in system calls would surely slow it down.

So ive thought i could try to keep a number of objects in memory so that i could just copy information into them, and use them without having to request the memory for them on demand. But how much memory should i try to reserve? Or should i not worry about that as long as the users computer has enough (presumably they will be focusing on the game and not running a weather simulation in the background).

What would be the best way of handling this?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: it depends on the expected lifetime of the objects.

Usually, the methods are combined.  An object that is fairly static and is unlikely to be removed or created often (usually, players, levels, certain objects in the levels, etc) are created with the first method you described (a list of objects, an array, a singleton, etc)  The exact method depends on the game, and the object being created.

For short term objects, like bullets, particle effects, or in some game, the enemies themselves, something like [object pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) is usually used.  A chunk of memory is reversed at the beginning of the game and reused throughout the course of the game for bullets and pretty particle effects.  As for *how much memory should I reserve?*, the ideal answer is "As little as possible".  Unfortunately, it's hard to figure that out sometimes.  The best way to figure it out is to take a guess at how many bullets or whatnot you plan on having on screen at any given time, multiply by two (for when you decide that your bullet hell shooter doesn't really work to well with only 50 bullets) and then add a little buffer.  To make it easier, store that value in a easily understood `#define BULLET_MAX 110` so you can change it when the game is closer to done, and you can reasonably be sure that the value isn't going to fluctuate as much.  For extra fun, you can tie the value into a config variable, and have the graphics setting affect it.

Answer (score 1):

In real time games, where fluidity is critical, they often allocate a large chunk of memory in the beginning of the level and avoids any allocation/deallocation in the middle of the game.

You can often design so the game mechanic prevents the game from running out of memory (such as increasing the chance of weapon jamming when the player shoots too much too often).

Ultimately though, test your game in your targeted minimum supported machine, if it's fast enough there then it's fast enough and don't overcomplicate your code for hypothetical situations.